# Slow page rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an issue with a partial that is rendered almost instantly for the first time navigating to that page, however if navigate away from that page and sometime later i come back it is rendered noticeably slow. It contains an ng-repeat on a list of about 140 items.

e.g: home (initialize) --> spells (instant) --> home --> spells (slow)

[GitHub Repository](https://github.com/Jasperras/planeswalkers/tree/master/app)

**Why does this happen and how do i fix it?**

Steps i've already taken to try and improve:

- Add bind-once in the repeater
- Use etags in my API so i don't get back a full list of the items i already have each time i load a partial.
- Added track by to ng-repeat.

**Code**

```
<div ng-repeat="color in ::colors">
  <div>
    <span data-target="#{{$index + 'col'}}">
      <header>
        <label>{{color.name}}</label>
      </header>
    </span>
  </div>

  <ul id="{{$index + 'col'}}">
    <li ng-repeat="spell in ::spells track by spell.name"  
        ng-if="spell.color.name === color.name" 
        ng-dblclick="addToCharacter(spell, 'spell')" 
        on-long-press="addToCharacter(spell, 'spell')">

      <div>
        <label ng-hide="isSpell(spell)">Ability</label>
        <label ng-show="isSpell(spell)">{{spell.cost}} mana</label>
      </div>

      <div data-target="#{{$index + 'sp'}}">
        <a>{{spell.name}}</a>
      </div>

      <div id="{{$index + 'sp'}}">
        {{spell.description}}
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

**IsSpell()**

```
$rootScope.isSpell = function (spell) {
    return spell.type != null && spell.cost != null;
};
```

Comment: Hard to say without diagnostics. Is `isSpell()` a fast function, like a getter? Also, try `ng-show` instead of `ng-if` for the `<li>` - maybe the browser is busy removing and inserting DOM elements.

Comment: Added the isSpell function in my post. I will try ng-show :)

Comment: Probably not the cause, but instead of using `isSpell` twice, just use it once on the parent `div`

Comment: Sadly ng-show seems to make it even slower.
@tymeJV will do :)

Comment: @Taerus, what do you mean by "for the first time"? How are you re-rendering?

Comment: Create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: @NewDev added a little sketch of the flow in the question.

Comment: @Taerus, are you doing a full-page redirect or are you changing a view? At any rate, I don't think there is enough data in the question to see the root cause

Comment: @NewDev It's only changing views. (Using angular-ui-router btw)

Comment: @Taerus is there any other angular view in the page that might cause that delay ? If so let us see  ,

Comment: @katmanco Added a link to the projects github repo.

Comment: @Taerus, why are you re-loading the `spells` every time you navigate to that state if it has already been loaded by the `MainCtrl`? It also causes the View to start generating the DOM, and then stop in the middle, and change everything, because everything is reloading - it may or may not play a factor, but you should understand why you need this. Aslo, why not load spells only when spells state is activated? And, not related, but you don't need to use `ng-init` everywhere in the View - when the controller function runs is where you should init whatever you need.

Comment: @NewDev i added that in order to have an updated list of everything if one with admin rights has added/edited something from the admin panel. That's why i've added etag support, so it only returns a 304 if nothing has been modified. If you've got any suggestions i'd gladly hear them :-) This is my first angularjs project after all.

Answer (score 0):

I have implement a little mechanism to only load the items when they are needed, so the page loads instantaneous and when the user clicks on a category (which is animated) it loads the items it needs. This all works very smoothly and i am quite happy with it.

*See the first div (colors) and the ng-if on the li*

```
<div ng-repeat="color in ::colors" ng-init="loadItems = false" ng-click="loadItems = true">
  <div>
    <span data-target="#{{$index + 'col'}}">
      <header>
        <label>{{color.name}}</label>
      </header>
    </span>
  </div>

  <ul id="{{$index + 'col'}}">
    <li ng-repeat="spell in ::spells track by spell.name"  
        ng-if="(spell.color.name === color.name) && (loadItems = true)" 
        ng-dblclick="addToCharacter(spell, 'spell')" 
        on-long-press="addToCharacter(spell, 'spell')">

      <div>
        <label ng-hide="isSpell(spell)">Ability</label>
        <label ng-show="isSpell(spell)">{{spell.cost}} mana</label>
      </div>

      <div data-target="#{{$index + 'sp'}}">
        <a>{{spell.name}}</a>
      </div>

      <div id="{{$index + 'sp'}}">
        {{spell.description}}
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```